# Handling REST Response Formats

Tags: web-applications, rest

It seems that newer websites (and API's especially) make use of request formats by adding the expected format to the end of the URL path.

```
/path/to/resource.html
/path/to/resource.json
/path/to/resource.xml
```

Are their any problems with this approach? Are there any studies or outlines of the pros and cons of doing this instead of just listing the resource without a file type extension?

Comment: `listing the resource without a file type extension` is not enough for a comparison (pros and cons). How would you identify the format in the "not extension approach"? Url segment? GET parameter? It doesn't really matter, to be honest, server side it doesn't make any difference and any approach is equally valid. There are some SEO resources out there that will argue that the extension approach is friendlier to search engine bots, but it's up to you if you want to take SEO "experts" seriously or not. I don't.

Comment: "Are their any problems with this approach?"?  How could there be any "cons" of any kind?  What are you imagining?  For non-REST static files this is the norm.  What would change in REST?  Please amplify on what kind of "problems" you imagine might happen.

Comment: @S.Lott: You are mistaken.  For non-REST static files that is **not** the norm.  The content-type header is.  Try it - your browser will ignore the url's extension and respect the header.  That is the standard in HTTP.

Comment: @qes: Interestingly, my default Apache setup which serves static files from a directory tree uses the file name and extension in the same obvious way that the question does.  The content type header -- on the response -- indicates the type of the response.  It doesn't indicate the type being requested.

Comment: @S.Lott: And that's simply a fallback to defaults in the absence of any more specific information.  The more appropriate way in HTTP for the client to request a specific content type is through the accepts header.  http://www.gethifi.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers

Comment: Similarly, a specific REST API could specify a default in the absence of something more specific, but the Accepts header would be the more "RESTful" way to request another representation.  I maintain the URL extensions should be a last resort, or the least preferred method.  What if you have multiple kinds of json representations, or xml representations - different schemas - would you prefer ".schema1.xml", ".schema2.xml".  I would say not, that accepts and content-type would be much more obviously the correct mechanism in that scenario.

Comment: @qes: The Accepts header is nice.  A `?format=JSON` isn't bad.  A `/path/to/json/resource` works also.  I'm not sure that it's helpful to be absolutist about the accepts header when there are other choices that seem like the work very nicely.

Comment: I don't think `Accepts` is ok for what the OP asked. It signals what you can accept, but not what you *want*.

Comment: @jjmontes: that's exactly what it is for.  There is no practical difference here between what you can accept and what you *want*.

Comment: @S.Lott: I don't intend to be absolutist, and you can see in my answer I provided four different ways to specify the format.  But the OP asked about REST.  Using an extension, and even so much more so using something like `/path/to/json/resource`, is **not** REST.  `?format=JSON`, using the query string, was the fourth item in my answer.  But using the path is practically an antithesis of REST.  If REST isn't what you or the OP wants, call it a Web API or REST-like.  REST means something fairly specific.

Answer (score 2):

From [xml.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/08/11/rest.html):

> A resource may have more than one representation. There are four frequently used ways of delivering the correct resource representation
>   to consumers:
>
> 1. Server-driven negotiation. The service provider determines the right representation from prior knowledge of its clients or uses the
>      information provided in HTTP headers like Accept, Accept-Charset,
>      Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, and User-Agent. The drawback of this
>      approach is that the server may not have the best knowledge about what
>      a client really wants.
> 2. Client-driven negotiation. A client initiates a request to a server. The server returns a list of available of representations. The
>      client then selects the representation it wants and sends a second
>      request to the server. The drawback is that a client needs to send two
>      requests.
> 3. Proxy-driven negotiation. A client initiates a request to a server through a proxy. The proxy passes the request to the server and
>      obtains a list of representations. The proxy selects one
>      representation according to preferences set by the client and returns
>      the representation back to the client.
> 4. URI-specified representation. A client specifies the representation it wants in the URI query string.

I would consider a URI based differentiation to be the least preferable method.

Answer (score 0):

Aside of SEO or aesthetics implications there are no pros or cons I know of.

Perhaps it could affect some caching setups that could avoid caching URLs with query strings (in the case you would use a query string argument to specify the format), but this is not really an issue of your API.

Perhaps it could be said that using extensions is more "REST" as it represents the resource in a better way. Perhaps some libraries/frameworks have a preference for some or other scheme in order to expose or access resources.

I wrote an article about the aspect of a few public REST APIs... perhaps it can help you: [a look into varios REST APIs](http://inmensosofa.blogspot.com/2011/10/look-into-various-rest-apis.html).

Comment: I would suggest extensions are the least "REST" as it creates multiple URI's to the same resource, whereas REST would prescribe that each individual resource have only one unique URI - it would also prescribe using the facilities that already exist in HTTP - i.e., the appropriate headers.

Comment: I would think the extension is the most REST since the type is embedded in the URI.

Comment: @S.Lott: The "type" is simply a representation of a resource.  Resources have global identifiers, not each representation of a resource. A core concept of REST is using the existing facilities of HTTP where appropriate, specifically including media type headers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).  What about links in the document?  Using extensions implies that you will also be altering all the links in the resource with the extension.  Using headers is much more appropriate.

Comment: Resources have global identifiers `/path/to/resource`. Followed by the type encoding after the resource ID, `.html` for example.  That's seems to provide a way to transfer the representation of an object's state in a specific encoding.  "altering all the links in the resource with the extension"?  What does this mean?

Comment: a REST resource without hyperlinks isn't REST.  So if I request a resource in json content, it should contain hyperlinks - e.g., a link to a related (sub) object (rather than containing the content of that resource - that is, a record of a person wouldn't embed the person's order info, it would contain links to the order resources themselves).  Using headers, the link would always be canonical "http://myapi.com/MyPerson/Order/1", but when using extensions I'd have to spit it out as ".../Order/1.json" or ".../Order/1.xml" depending.  The client should use the accepts header for this, not ext.

Comment: @qes: If a client makes a JSON format request, `/path/to/resource.json`, then the response (in JSON) can contain object references in JSON, right?  `/path/to/related/resource.json`  That seems pretty much what they'd expect, right?  What's hateful about producing that as output?  You're RESTful service had to encode the object in the requested notation.  Why not encode the links along with the rest of the object's state?  I don't see what problem is created.

Comment: Most state-of-the-art providers, however, don't use hyperlinks but IDs. They expect you to build URLs using the IDs, which makes sense in many cases where the same ID can be part of the URL used to access several other resources.

Comment: @jjmontes: without hyperlinks, then it's really not REST, it's just a plain web api. "Representational State Transfer is intended to evoke an image of how a well-designed Web application behaves: ... where the user progresses through an application by selecting links (state transitions)" - from Roy Fielding's Ph.D. dissertation, which is the seminal work describing REST.

Comment: @jjmontes: as just one example: http://blog.theamazingrando.com/your-web-service-might-not-be-restful-if "If Your Web Services Do Any of These Things, You’re Doing it Wrong ... Clients have to concatenate strings to get to the next resource."

Comment: @qes I agree with most of your points here and indeed REST signals that hyperlinks should be used to reference resources. However, trying not to be drastic, I think there are cases where "manual composition" of URLs is just ok (also saves servers some trafic by reducing redundant URLs which can be composited anyway). But in any case: you are right of course, and thanks a lot for the link!